# Abstract Factory 'am I doing it correctly' based on this code

Tags: c#

Without knowing my implementation can you assume that this is the correct way to use abstract factory? I have been using http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern to get a firm understanding of the pattern but find myself in a position. The position I am in is for each new control type I will have to add an else if... code smell?

Thanks in advance.

```
private void RenderInputType(StringBuilder renderedControlList, dynamic type, dynamic item, dynamic name)
    {
        if (type == "ButtonModal")
        {
            // new factory to handle complex types
            HtmlFiveInputFactory complex = new ModalControlFactory();
            HtmlInputWorld world = new HtmlInputWorld(complex);
            world.RunExecutionPlan(renderedControlList, item, name);
        }
        else if (type == "CheckBoxIf")
        {
            HtmlFiveInputFactory complex = new CheckBoxIfControlFactory();
            HtmlInputWorld world = new HtmlInputWorld(complex);
            world.RunExecutionPlan(renderedControlList, item, name);
        }
        else if (type == "ListView")
        {
            // very complex, checkbox toggle per row, buttonmodal, checkboxif
        }
        else
        {
            InputFactory inputFactory = new HtmlInputFactory(_htmlInputService);
            inputFactory.CreateInput(renderedControlList, type, item, name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Silence is confirmation?